# AWS Server Migration Service fails on Upload to S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, vmware-esxi, migration

I have followed instructions on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/latest/userguide/server-migration.html to migrate servers from vSphere ESX hosts to AWS but on UI dashboard it fails on step 2 from 4 and error messages is:

```
Latest run's status messageServerError: Failed to upload base disk(s) to S3. Please try again. If this problem persists, please contact AWS support: com.vmware.vim25.ManagedObjectNotFound: HttpNfcLease:session[3c562463-edb0-ac3a-ca92-95369d512e0c]52c6b1ad-38bf-2911-e92d-aaa66639f4a7
```

Which looks like exception on VMware API call. When tailing sms-replications-poller.log on SMS Connector, i can see:

```
sms-job-xxxxx:sms-run-xxxxx:UploadBaseSnapshot SnapshotStream:150 - Waiting for lease to get ready
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you have the proper IAM permissions?

Comment: Did you contact AWS support as suggested?

Comment: Unfortunately it is too expensive for us to ask for supported account. But I could see that an S3 folder was created by the connector server that its name starts with "sms-b-ap-southeast-"

Answer (score 0):

Definitely there were some problems with the VMs being migrated such as broken iso image mount.

After several try found that the safest way is to:

1. Clone the VM
2. Shutdown cloned VM and remove CD/DVD and Floppy drives
3. Migrate the cloned VM using AWS SMS